# Changing numbers in Excel to percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am working on an intense needs report that has multiple sheets of data.  the numbers now have to be converted to percentages.  but when I click the % sign in excel, it doesn't allow me to move the decimal so it is accurate.  Is there a way to just add a % sign after the numbers?

Example:
27
15
69

Comment: What is your example?  Example input? Please share desired output too.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers should be divided by 100 then apply % from the Ribbon to have the real percentage or you can write % by double clicking in each cell and press `Shift + %`
`Example: 0.27 is the number = 27%`
To understand how Excel works with percentage [Click Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-numbers-as-percentages-0bda4354-a8a9-42ad-892f-3d23cca668ff)